# Springboot - list of objects with child entities not returned

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I have this object named SubmittedQuiz, it consists of a Quiz object, User object and submittedQuestions object.

When I try to do this request:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/SubmittedQuiz/getForUser/10
```

I get returned the following error:

> Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->edowl.Model.SubmittedQuiz["user"]->edowl.Model.User$HibernateProxy$lNsgwyQb["hibernateLazyInitializer"])"

The request finds the objects fine, when setting breakpoints it actually gets the list of objects however it fails on the return statement.

The controller method is as shown below:

```
@GetMapping("/getForUser/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<List<SubmittedQuiz>> getSubmittedQuizForUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    List<SubmittedQuiz> quizzes = submittedQuizService.findAllByUserId(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(quizzes, HttpStatus.OK); //ok is 200 status code
}
```

The ***Service*** is shown below:

```
public List<SubmittedQuiz> findAllByUserId(Long id) {
   return submittedQuizRepo.findAllByUserId(id);
}
```

The ***Repo*** is shown below:

```
List<SubmittedQuiz> findAllByUserId(Long id);
```

The `SubmittedQuiz` is shown below:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Submitted_Quiz")
public class SubmittedQuiz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "User_Quiz_Submitted",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_submitted_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
    public User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "Quiz_Quiz_Submitted",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_submitted_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id")})
    public Quiz quiz;

    private float score;
    private LocalDate generatedDate;
    private float timeTaken;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "quiz_submitted_question",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_submitted_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")})
    @Column(name = "submitted_questions")
    private Set<SubmittedQuestion> submittedQuestions = new HashSet<>();
```

I saw one suggestion about putting `@JsonBackReference` & `@JsonManagedReference`  annotations on the objects.
However I haven't needed to do this on any other object thus far and the current annotations I have used sufficed fine till this point

***Are there any suggestions?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use [EntityGraph](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph) for this purpose.

And set to `atributePaths` all entities which have `FetchType.LAZY`:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"user", "quiz", "submitted_questions"})
List<SubmittedQuiz> findAllByUserId(Long id);
```

Some hint for controller - you don't need to set `200` response directly. Status code `OK` is returned by default. So following will be fine:

```
@GetMapping("/getForUser/{id}")
public List<SubmittedQuiz> getSubmittedQuizForUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    return submittedQuizService.findAllByUserId(id);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Try to add web configuration like::

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public Module datatypeHibernateModule() {
        return new Hibernate5Module();
    }
}
```

If it wouldn't help to solve the issue with the error try to add:

> @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})

to all your subentities:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(...)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public User user;
```

---

Also, **JPA** API requires that your entities have to be serializable.
You have to update it like follows:

```
public class SubmittedQuiz implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Add the same for other entities as well (***User***, ***Quiz***...)

Comment: error persists when using @entityGraph

Comment: @ABpositive updated the answer

Comment: @ABpositive which part of the answer solved the issue?